# g++ linker cannot find symbols that are apparently exported

Tags: c++, linux, linker-errors

I am trying to compile mod_tile, but it fails after upgrading from Mapnik 2.2 to 3.0 (I checked that only 3.0 versions of the packages exist).

During linking there are now undefined references. The linker command is

```
g++ -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mapnik/agg -I/usr/include/mapnik -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -DMAPNIK_MEMORY_MAPPED_FILE -DMAPNIK_HAS_DLCFN -DBIGINT -DBOOST_REGEX_HAS_ICU -DHAVE_JPEG -DMAPNIK_USE_PROJ4 -DHAVE_PNG -DHAVE_WEBP -DHAVE_TIFF -DLINUX -DMAPNIK_THREADSAFE -DBOOST_SPIRIT_NO_PREDEFINED_TERMINALS=1 -DBOOST_PHOENIX_NO_PREDEFINED_TERMINALS=1 -DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3=1 -DNDEBUG -DHAVE_CAIRO -DGRID_RENDERER -DHAVE_LIBXML2 -std=c++11 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mapnik-3.0.12+ds=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -pthread -ftemplate-depth-300 -Wsign-compare -Wshadow -O2 -g -O2 -o .libs/renderd src/daemon.o src/daemon_compat.o src/renderd-gen_tile.o src/sys_utils.o src/request_queue.o src/cache_expire.o src/renderd-metatile.o src/renderd-parameterize_style.o src/protocol_helper.o src/store.o src/store_file.o src/store_file_utils.o src/store_memcached.o src/store_rados.o src/store_ro_http_proxy.o src/store_ro_composite.o src/store_null.o -pthread -Wl,-z -Wl,relro -Wl,-z -Wl,now -g0 -pthread  -L/usr/lib -lmapnik -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_filesystem -lboost_regex -lcairo -lpng /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so -lwebp -lxml2 -licui18n -lboost_system -lharfbuzz -ljpeg -licuuc /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so -lz -ldl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so -Liniparser3.0b/.libs /home/fheer/src/mod_tile/iniparser3.0b/.libs/libiniparser.so -lm -pthread
```

The first of the errors is

```
src/renderd-gen_tile.o: In function `load_fonts(char const*, int)':
mod_tile/src/gen_tile.cpp:175: undefined reference to `mapnik::freetype_engine::register_font(std::string const&)'
```

libmapnik.so is searched for in /usr/lib, where it exists. nm shows the symbol in question to exist:

```
$ nm -D /usr/lib/libmapnik.so|grep register_font
0000000000150920 T _ZN6mapnik15freetype_engine13register_fontERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
0000000000150c90 T _ZN6mapnik15freetype_engine14register_fontsERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEb
000000000014f2c0 T _ZN6mapnik15freetype_engine18register_font_implERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERNS_12font_libraryERSt3mapIS6_St4pairIiS6_ESt4lessIS6_ESaISC_IS7_SD_EEE
00000000001509f0 T _ZN6mapnik15freetype_engine19register_fonts_implERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERNS_12font_libraryERSt3mapIS6_St4pairIiS6_ESt4lessIS6_ESaISC_IS7_SD_EEEb
00000000001abfc0 T _ZN6mapnik3Map14register_fontsERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEb
```

I searched for this error, but only found solutions for problems that are not the case here. Maybe I oversee something obvious, any pointers would be appreciated! I just don't see what else I could check for.

Comment: Try adding `-lmapnik` again at the end of the linker command.  If it succeeds, or you get different undefined symbols instead, it's an issue with library order.

Comment: Sadly, no change in the errors, all complaints are only regarding the Mapnik-Library. Other libraries I had updated and which reside in /usr/lib/ as well are accepted correctly by the linker.

Comment: It must have been an issue with gcc 4.9 one way or another. Upgraded to gcc 6, now it compiles okay. No idea what the reason is, but yesterday the compilation with Mapnik 2.2 and gcc 4.9 and the same mod_tile-source went through without an issue.